# Can I use multiple selectors in :host() argument?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is working:

```css
:host(.foo) .title,
:host(.bar) .title {
  ...
}
```

I was expecting this to work, but it didn't:

```css
:host(.foo, .bar) .title {
  ...
}
```

Am I missing something? Or is this a browser bug? I'm using Firefox 100.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:host()` selector accept a `compound-selector` and not `simple-selector-list` so you cannot use comma separated classes (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector).

You can try `:host(is(.foo, .bar)) .title` instead. It may work.

Comment: That should be "not a `simple-selector-list`" rather than "not `complex-selector`". Whether `:is(.foo, ,bar)` qualifies as a compound selector is [an open question](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6737)

Comment: @Alohci I suspected it was not going to be as simple as that.